# Problem with notifications not showing in android 10 java

Tags: java, android

Problem with notifications not showing  in android 10  java..

Private code android studio,
Notifications work in Android on all releases, repeating 10,
In the problem,
I want to change this code to work

callingUid=10339, userId=0, incomingUserId=0, notificationUid=10339, notification=Notification(channel=null pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=default sound=default tick defaults=0xffffffff flags=0x11 color=0x00000000 actions=2 vis=PRIVATE)

```
public class MNotification {

    private static final String NOTIFICATION_TAG = "M";


    public static void notify(final Context context,
                              final String exampleString, final int number) {
        final Resources res = context.getResources();

        // This image is used as the notification's large icon (thumbnail).
        // TODO: Remove this if your notification has no relevant thumbnail.
        final Bitmap picture = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.example_picture);


        final String ticker = exampleString;
        final String title = res.getString(
                R.string.m_notification_title_template, exampleString);
        final String text = res.getString(
                R.string.m_notification_placeholder_text_template, exampleString);

        final NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)

                // Set appropriate defaults for the notification light, sound,
                // and vibration.
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)

                // Set required fields, including the small icon, the
                // notification title, and text.
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_m)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(text)

                // All fields below this line are optional.

                // Use a default priority (recognized on devices running Android
                // 4.1 or later)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)

                // Provide a large icon, shown with the notification in the
                // notification drawer on devices running Android 3.0 or later.
                .setLargeIcon(picture)

                // Set ticker text (preview) information for this notification.
                .setTicker(ticker)

                // Show a number. This is useful when stacking notifications of
                // a single type.
                .setNumber(number)
                // If this notification relates to a past or upcoming event, you
                // should set the relevant time information using the setWhen
                // method below. If this call is omitted, the notification's
                // timestamp will by set to the time at which it was shown.
                // TODO: Call setWhen if this notification relates to a past or
                // upcoming event. The sole argument to this method should be
                // the notification timestamp in milliseconds.
                //.setWhen(...)

                // Set the pending intent to be initiated when the user touches
                // the notification.
                .setContentIntent(
                        PendingIntent.getActivity(
                                context,
                                0,
                                new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com")),
                                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))

                // Show expanded text content on devices running Android 4.1 or
                // later.
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                        .bigText(text)
                        .setBigContentTitle(title)
                        .setSummaryText("Dummy summary text"))

                // Example additional actions for this notification. These will
                // only show on devices running Android 4.1 or later, so you
                // should ensure that the activity in this notification's
                // content intent provides access to the same actions in
                // another way.
                .addAction(
                        R.drawable.ic_action_stat_share,
                        res.getString(R.string.action_share),
                        PendingIntent.getActivity(
                                context,
                                0,
                                Intent.createChooser(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                                        .setType("text/plain")
                                        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Dummy text"), "Dummy title"),
                                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
                .addAction(
                        R.drawable.ic_action_stat_reply,
                        res.getString(R.string.action_reply),
                        null)

                // Automatically dismiss the notification when it is touched.
                .setAutoCancel(true);

            notify(context, builder.build());


    }

    @SuppressLint("ObsoleteSdkInt")
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR)
    private static void notify(final Context context, final Notification notification) {
        final NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR) {
            nm.notify(NOTIFICATION_TAG, 0, notification);
        } else {
            nm.notify(NOTIFICATION_TAG.hashCode(), notification);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Cancels any notifications of this type previously shown using
     * {@link #notify(Context, String, int)}.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR)
    public static void cancel(final Context context) {
        final NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR) {
            nm.cancel(NOTIFICATION_TAG, 0);
        } else {
            nm.cancel(NOTIFICATION_TAG.hashCode());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need create NotificationChannel for your notification https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels

Comment: What code add this to work?